# Snowflake SQL - Invalid escape sequence when using Regexp_Like

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been migrating something from a netezza based SQL script into Snowflake, and part of one of my join clauses has the following lines:

```
AND regexp_like(hist.Description, p.RegexPattern, 'i')
```

This runs fine on Netezza, however when running within Snowflake I get the following error after about 2 minutes of run time:

```
100048 (2201B): Invalid regular expression: '^Renewal\b.*\bDraft\b.*\bPending\b\h+\bNon-Renewal\b.*', invalid escape sequence: \h
```

Has anyone ever encountered this error? A bit new to regexp_like function so it may be something simple, but haven't  been able to find anything regarding a fix online. Not sure what the error is really telling me?

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda for the reply. I understand what this should be doing, however when implementing it, it sets all text after the replace as red, like its wrapped everything else in ' '?

Comment: It appears like its not having a problem with the \b. It doesn't understand the \h. I'm not familiar with the SQL regex. I assume \b matches a blank. What is \h supposed to match?

Comment: My understanding is the \h is the escape when it runs in Netezza SQL, but I guess its different in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\h is a Perl 5 escape sequence to match horizontal whitespace per [Perl Regular Expression Classes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Backslash-sequences). [Snowflake regular expressions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html) don't appear to support \h. The closest alternative would be to use \s. Note that \s will match a few characters that \h will not, so you may want to verify whether you have any of those characters before making the substitution. See the Perl reference for details.

Comment: Thanks very much for the links and explanation. That makes sense and helps a lot. With this, I should be able to unblock.

Comment: Unless your data includes the Unicode characters that \h will match, you could also replace \h with space or tab or non-breaking space: ( |\t|\xa0)